# SCALA Lift MongoDB MongoRecord compilation errors

Tags: scala, mongodb, lift

I'm attempting to setup a simple DB for the Scala Lift (2.4) framework

Below is my **User.scala** model.

```
package code.model

import net.liftweb.mongodb._
import net.liftweb.json.JsonDSL._
import com.mongodb._

class User private() extends MongoRecord[User] with ObjectIdPk[User] {

    def meta = User

    object name extends StringField(this, 50)
    object level extends IntField(this)

}

object User extends User with MongoMetaRecord[User]
```

When compiling I get 7 errors, but think they are all related to this first one:

```
[error] C:\Lift2.4\scala_29\conference\src\main\scala\code\model\User.scala:7:
not found: type MongoRecord
```

Any help is much appreciated, I'm sure I'm not importing something right or have missed something obvious.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add

```
import net.liftweb.mongodb.record._ 
import net.liftweb.mongodb.record.field._ 
import net.liftweb.record.field._ 
import net.liftweb.record._
```

example of model
https://github.com/foursquare/rogue/blob/master/src/test/scala/com/foursquare/rogue/QueryTest.scala
For queries, you can use [Rogue: A Type-Safe Scala DSL for querying MongoDB](http://engineering.foursquare.com/2011/01/21/rogue-a-type-safe-scala-dsl-for-querying-mongodb/)

Comment: Not constructive toward answering the question

Comment: let's see the next question. about how to make query. )

Answer (score 1):

```
import net.liftweb.mongodb.record._
```

Answer (score 0):

`MongoRecord` (and `MongoMetaRecord`) is in `net.liftweb.mongodb.record`, so you’ll have to add

```
import net.liftweb.mongodb.record._
```

and of course take care that these are included with sbt.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at https://github.com/rohit-tingendab/ks-lift, it is a working kick starter for Lift + MongoDB.